# Woocommerce - Add to cart button on template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a template for my wordpress site.

The template loops trough woocommerce products and prints out some information (image, description, price and so on)

The issue I am facing is with the "add to cart" button.

This is the code I have:

```
<a href="/cart/?add-to-cart=<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>" rel="nofollow" data-product-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
```

and I am trying to NOT redirect after the button is clicked.

I already have:

> Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives

ticked as options, but I can't find how to not redirect after button is clicked.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your href is `"/cart/?add-to-cart=<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>"` which basicaly sais that you redirect to the cart page and add the product to the cart.

Try it like this `href="?add-to-cart=<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>"`, it should keep you on the same page.

Comment: It was so simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In `add-to-cart.js`, the event is bind to button with `add_to_cart_button` and `ajax_add_to_cart` classes and the `data-product_id` attribute.

Comment: Do I need both the classes, or since I just need the ajax method I can use only ajax_add_to_cart?

Comment: You will need both. Take a look at the source to see how Ajax cart work: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js.

Comment: Following the js file, if button has .add_to_cart_button (which it does) and has the product id attr, it should add a class, but it doesn't...the button looks like this:
<button data-product_id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>"
                                class="add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart btn btn-hg hg-product-add-to-cart-button ">Add to cart
                        </button>

Comment: Do you think that the above solution will work through the AJAX?

Comment: @somethingnow the solution I mentioned IS through AJAX, what are you talking about?